# Problema en app Android( No repetir id con respecto a otros datos) SQL

Tags: javascript, mysql, android, android-studio

Tengo una app la cual se usa para votas tatuajes en una exposicion, mi problema es que quiero que el CI pueda votar una vez por participante, es decir que " CI=1234 pueda votar una vez sola a Participante Nº1, Participante Nº2, Participante Nº3,etc. Basicamente seria que no se repita el CI con respecto al Participante...Donde dice LO QUE QUIERO QUE PASE (Seria el funcionamiento)

[image: Imagen 1]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola @JoaquinCaceres, bienvenid@ a Stack Overflow, te sugiero completar el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del lugar y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. También puedes revisar la sección de [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas respuestas de calidad.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes colocar el campo de la tabla como unico por lo tanto ese dato que se ingrese no se pude volver a repetir

```
ALTER TABLE `table` ADD UNIQUE( `campo_tabla`);
```

Espero y te funcione, saludos